# Show that $f:A\to B$ is injective iff $f(A\backslash X) = f(A)\backslash f(X)$ for all $X\subset A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Show that the function $f:A\to B$ is injective if, and only if, $f(A\backslash X) = f(A)\backslash f(X)$ for all $X\subset A$

I can prove that $f(A\backslash X) \subset f(A)\backslash f(X)$:

$y\in f(A\backslash X)\implies \exists x\in A\backslash X$ s.t. $y=f(x).$ $x\in A\backslash X \iff x\in A \;\land\; x\notin X \iff y\in f(A) \;\land\; y\notin f(X) \iff y\in f(A)\backslash f(X)$.

But I'm having trouble proving that $f(A)\backslash f(X) \subset f(A\backslash X)$. Here's what I got so far:

$y\in f(A)\backslash f(X) \iff y\in f(A) \;\land\; y\notin f(X).$ $\exists a \in A$ s.t. $y=f(a) \;\land\; \not\exists x \in X$ s.t. $y=f(x)$
But I can't figure out the rest of the proof.

I also have no idea on how I would prove the other way around, i.e., that $f(A\backslash X) = f(A)\backslash f(X)$ implies that $f$ is injective.

Comment: You haven't used the assumption that $f$ is injective yet.

Comment: @moboDawn_φ I think it's necessary only for proving that $f(A)\backslash f(X) \subset f(A\backslash X)$, but I can't figure out how I would use it in the proof

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A$ and choose $X = \{x\}$. The assumption means that $f(A\smallsetminus \{x\}) = f(A) \smallsetminus \{f(x)\}$. If $y\in A$ is not equal to $x$, then $y\in A\smallsetminus \{x\}$ implies that $f(y) \in f(A\smallsetminus \{x\}) = f(A)\smallsetminus \{f(x)\}$, so that $f(y)\neq f(x)$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.